# How to make SYN FLood via HPING

Tags: security, networking

I  attacked  my target server 'TARGET_SERVER_IP' with SYN Flood attack

To check if my server can stand the SYN attack with the command `sudo hping3 -i u1 -S  -c 9999999999 TARGET_SERVER_IP`

However when I was running the above command, then I can not ping any other server like Google or Yahoo.

In other words, I found I can ping not nothing during the time.

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 948
Request timeout for icmp_seq 949
Request timeout for icmp_seq 950
```

I didn't prevent the SYN attack on the target server,

I suppose it should be out of service, but it didn't. (My server is running on AMAZON.)

Any error in my test command ? `sudo hping3 -i u1 -S  -c 9999999999 TARGET_SERVER_IP`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

First, please check man pages to see if your command has the right parameters.Secondly, Amazon AWS may have either a prevention mechanism or network component is very strong. You may need to monitor your server at Amazon AWS, without monitoring it's really hard to find the reason.

hping has many options, this is what I used to test my server:

`hping  --rand-source -S -d 500 -p 80 -i em0 WWW.WEBPAGE.COM`